# Question regrading which files are needed by tessnet2.dll

Tags: c#, tessnet2

I made an application for an automated invoice management system for my company. I am using the tessnet2 library for OCR. The whole application works properly on my development machine but as soon as I put the code on the target machine, wihout the development framework, it gives an error of references not found in the .DoOCR method.

I read that you had the same problem and I hope you can help me with it.

I have put the language files in the same directory as the application itself, but its not helping me.

Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Regards

Vin

Answer (score 0):

Look in the VS folder (under Program Files - you'll need to look in sub-folders) for a program called "Depends".  This looks for dependencies from EXE and DLL files.  Run it with the DLL as a command-line parameter, and that should list what files are needed by that DLL.  Then see if they are all present on the destination system.